# Resizing axes on matplotlib_toolkits ImageGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I've been trying (unsuccessfully) for a while now to get three vertically stacked pcolormesh plots to share the one colorbar. A variety of Google searches led me to the ImageGrid feature in the matplotlib toolkit, which I'm starting to like (although I don't quite understand it).

One particular feature I can't seem to find is the ability to "stretch" an axes object(s) across multiple columns, as can be done with the colspan argument in subplot2grid. Playing around with the demo code [found here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axes_grid2.html), I get to the point of being able to produce this image.

As you can see, it's currently centered in the middle of the figure space, with an amount of whitespace on either side equal to the width of what I assume is the central axes width. Simply, I'd like each of those three plots to stretch over the width of the space, while keeping the colorbar on the right hand side of the plots and at this height.

[image]

So far, my attempted code (which is really just the sample code with bits missing). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np


def get_demo_image():
    from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
    f = get_sample_data("axes_grid/bivariate_normal.npy", asfileobj=False)
    z = np.load(f)
    # z is a numpy array of 15x15
    return z, (-3, 4, -4, 3)

if 1:
    F = plt.figure(1, (6, 6))
    F.clf()

    # prepare images
    Z, extent = get_demo_image()
    ZS = [Z[i::3, :] for i in range(3)]
    extent = extent[0], extent[1]/3., extent[2], extent[3]

    # demo 2 : shared colorbar
    grid2 = ImageGrid(F, 111,
                      nrows_ncols=(3, 1),
                      direction="column",
                      axes_pad=0,
                      add_all=True,
                      label_mode="1",
                      share_all=False,
                      cbar_location="right",
                      cbar_mode="single",
                      cbar_size="10%",
                      cbar_pad=0.05,
                      )

    grid2[0].set_xlabel("X")
    grid2[0].set_ylabel("Y")

    vmax, vmin = np.max(ZS), np.min(ZS)
    import matplotlib.colors
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmax=vmax, vmin=vmin)

    for ax, z in zip(grid2, ZS):
        im = ax.imshow(z, norm=norm,
                       origin="lower", extent=extent,
                       interpolation="nearest")

    # With cbar_mode="single", cax attribute of all axes are identical.
    ax.cax.colorbar(im)
    ax.cax.toggle_label(True)

    grid2[0].set_xticks([-2, 0])
    grid2[0].set_yticks([-2, 0, 2])

    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You could try changing the `aspect` of your `imshow`s. For example, setting `aspect=0.5` should stretch the figures in the horizontal direction. By default, this will be set to 1, i.e. the distance on the x axis is equal to the equivalent distance on the y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageGrid` is designed to host images of equal aspect ratio. If you don't want to have images with equal aspect, using usual subplots is probably much easier. To locate the subplots on a grid, using [`matplotlib.gridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) is helpful.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 2, width_ratios=[1,.05])
fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0)

norm=plt.Normalize(0,1)
for i in range(3):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i,0])
    im= ax.imshow(np.random.rand(5,36)*0.3+i*0.3, norm=norm, aspect="auto")

cax = fig.add_subplot(gs[:,1])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm after - thank you! Reading through the documentation and seeing that I can still use ax parameters makes things a lot simpler. I may have to start using this as my default - I create a lot of plots like this.